# Nginx on CentOS: How can I change the "Server" header?

Tags: nginx, centos, http, http-headers, headers

I'm running Nginx on Centos6.

For security reasons I'd like to change/remove the `Server` HTTP header contained in the response headers.

For instance,nginx's default `Sever` header looks like:I'm running Nginx on Centos6.

For security reasons I'd like to ch
`Server: nginx/1.12.2`
But I'd like it to show something like:
`Server: mystartup/1.0`.
I tried these site confiurations, but none have worked.

```
server_tokens off;
proxy_pass_header 'New Server Name';
```

My server configuration:
CentOS 6.9
Nginx version 1.12.2

Answer (score 4):

You probably want `add_header Server "mystartup/1.0" always`.

Comment: Where do you get `set_header` from?

Comment: i tried but when i'm running this flag i'm getting nginx configuration error. nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: @MichaelHampton